# Ubuntu 12.04 Bluetooth problem

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

I turn on Bluetooth service from command line `sudo service bluetooth start` and check status of Bluetooth service it showing me Bluetooth is on.

When I try to search my laptop for connection it's not showing me my laptop in that list. What is the problem. Need Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember I had the same problem.
I can't remember if I could or could not see my laptop in my mobile device, but I do remember having some connectivity issues.
What worked for me was to install "Bluetooth Manager". This solved my problems.
I think that you install this app with the command: `sudo apt-get install blueman`.
I hope this helps...

Comment: I did this but its not working. Actually It showing blue is on but I am not able to find my device. :( any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any other solution. Try troubleshooting further: do you have any way to check if your mobile device can "see" other bluetooth devices? Can you check if the bluetooth in your laptop is visible in other mobiles? Can you check if the bluetooth in your laptop works in a different OS (such as windows)?

Answer (score 0):

Most bluetooth devices are invisible by default.

I use Unity, so I would click the bluetooth icon in the top bar, and tick the visible switch from off to on.

If you have gnome, or prefer to use the command line, I can't help you.